# Native Windows Libraries Under Wine

Tags: linux, performance, wine, dll

As we know, Wine has the ability to run windows native Dlls instead of it's own library files. For example you can use the original d3dx9.dll instead of wine's own d3dx9.dll implementation.

Does anyone have good stats on performance differences between native and wine libraries? Has anyone tried and had success implementing library supports to Wine by using library files not provided by Wine (like WPF), can it even be done?

In a comprehensive question, what are the performance differences between common native dlls versus wine dlls for games and more intense programs? And can support for new programs be added by fetching a native dll from windows that hasn't been implemented yet to wine in it's open source form?

Comment: http://wiki.winehq.org/Debunking_Wine_Myths

Comment: Yes, myth debunk 3.1; wine can run native DLLs, as I said at the start of my question. I'm wondering about the differences between native and wine's own dlls in performance and functionality, and if there are functionalities that can be added to wine by tossing a few native dlls in there since wine doesn't have it's own dlls for these things.

Comment: If there is a Wine DLL it is usually best because it was only made because the native DLL was problematic for some reason. In general, Wine supports Windows DLLs just fine. The DLLs which cause problems are those that perform low level functions. That would include DX and anything else hardware related.

Comment: @krowe if you're confident about this, feel free to write it up as an answer :)

Comment: 5 years ago I would've. Now, I haven't used it in so long that I don't have that level of confidence.